# How can I use MKNetworkKit to Implementation Proxy

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, mknetworkkit

Now I`m trying to switch AsiHttpRequest to MKNetworkKit, since MKNetworkKit doesn`t provide the Proxy method like Asi, so how can i make it work?

Comment: what have you try for find this..? did you use Google for Find this and have you read it's documentation.

Comment: yeah,I`m trying all of this. the documentation doesn`t clear.